# Continuum hypothesis and quantum theory - is there system with Hilbert space dimension cardinality between integers and reals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, mathematics

I wonder about the possible influences of the continuum hypothesis or its negation on quantum theory.
Could we think about a physical system for which Hilbert space would have dimension cardinality (cardinality of orthonormal basis set) between integers and reals (thus in favour of continuum hypothesis negation)?
J.

Comment: The problem wouldn't be very undecidable if we could.

Comment: I would also have to point out that we have experimental access to at most an integer infinity; How would the OP propose that we distinguish between the different cardinalities operationally?

Comment: For any uncountable basis we need integrals instead of sums, so your proposal would require a model in which $\Bbb R$ has subsets which, in addition to meeting your stated cardinality constraint, are of nonzero measure.

Answer (score 0):

Any quantum system can be simulated to arbitrary accuracy by a universal quantum computer

https://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk/wp-content/deutsch85.pdf

https://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk/wp-content/ItFromQubit.pdf

A universal quantum computer can compute the same set of functions as a classical Turing machine. So if it is impossible to compute a function with a classical Turing machine, it is also impossible to compute it with a quantum system.

Since the continuum problem is undecidable there is no algorithm for either a classical or quantum computer that gives a true or false answer to it. So no quantum system can decide the continuum problem.